# How to read user inputted Strings where whitespace exists in the middle using `scan`?

Tags: r

I want to collect strings entered by a user into a vector, some of these strings will be multiple words. I am currently using:

```
terms = scan(strip.white = TRUE, sep = NULL, what = character())
```

This works, but if the user enters `'blue car'`, the vector is stored as `("blue", "car")` and not `("blue car")`.

I can get around it by asking the user to enter the term as `'"blue car"'` i.e. wrapped in a string, but that isnt ideal.

I have checked the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/scan) but I dont see anything which resolves this. Is anyone aware of a workaround?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you just `paste(terms, collapse = " ")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine if you change the separator.

```
terms = scan(strip.white = TRUE, sep = '\n', what = character())
1: blue
2: car
3: blue cars
4: 
Read 3 items
terms
#[1] "blue"      "car"       "blue cars"
```

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry, I am not sure how I didnt get that to work. Works perfectly. Thank you Ronak!